# Start rostopic echo within launch?

Tags: matlab, roslaunch, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All!

I want to save data with "`rostopic echo -p > filname`" like shown here:
[link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Plotting%20controller%20data%20in%20matlab)

Is it possible to start echo recording with my launch file and how?
Is there any other way to record and import data to matlab in a convenient way?
Thx for help!!!

Bye

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32910/start-rostopic-echo-within-launch?/) by [rascal](https://answers.ros.org/users/2220/rascal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-04-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One solution would be to wrap this call into a python node for instance system.exec and the subprocess module ([on python.org](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html)).
This node can then be started by a roslaunch file.

However, I would highly recommend that you use rosbag instead, this is a much more reliable tool that rostopic. For instance you can do:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="rosbag" type="rosbag" name="rosbag_record"
    args="record -o /tmp/slam-map /wide/left/image_raw /wide/left/camera_info /wide/right/image_raw /wide/right/camera_info /rosout"/>
</launch>
```

Here you will have in `/tmp` a rosbag file beginning with slam-map followed by the current date and time.

It is then quite straightforward to convert a file to a csv file which can then be read by matlab or whatever 3rd party tool you use. See the [rosbag API](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag) to know how to do so.
I also have written a converter rosbag to csv, it is not in a public repository but if you are interested I can post it here.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2012-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Holton](https://answers.ros.org/users/4514/holton/) on 2013-04-16**:
Hello, sir, I am new in ROS, I am wondering how to covert a bag file into csv, could you please give me more hint? please! Thank you!